# Not able to read property at runtime

Tags: vb6

When I tried to read the `"Left property"` of a control, it is giving me the error,

`"Left cannot be read at run time"`

Here is my code,

```
for each ctrl in me.controls
    if ctrl.left > 2490 then
        'app logic
    end if
next
```

what is wrong in this code. It worked without error in another computer.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have a design-time only placeable control on your form like a `timer` for example, that does not have a run-time left property. You could check the type of control to ensure only `TextBox`, `Label`, `Button`, etc. get checked, or just use an `on error resume next`:

Check for object type using `TypeOf`:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Timer Then
    Else
        If ctrl.Left > 2490 Then
            'app logic
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Check for object type using `TypeName`:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "Timer" Then
    Else
        If ctrl.Left > 2490 Then
            'app logic
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Using `On Error Resume Next`:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

On Error Resume Next
for each ctrl in me.controls
    if ctrl.left > 2490 then
        'app logic
    end if
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the last method, it's important to handle errors inline reraising any unexpected error.  Otherwise if you get any different error than the one you're expecting you could have a very tough time finding it.  So:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

On Error Resume Next
for each ctrl in me.controls
    if ctrl.left > 2490 then
        Select Case Err.Number
           Case 0        'No Error, ignore
           Case 393      'The error you want to ignore 
              Err.Clear  'Reset for next iteration
           Case Else
              On Error Goto 0
              Err.Raise Err.Number  'Reraise any unexpected errors
        End Select
        'app logic
    end if
Next
On Error Goto 0
```